# How to know if a user logged in through facebook

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6, dotnetnuke-module

I have both DNN 6.2 and DNN 7.0 running on my localhost.

I have successfully set up facebook authentication and got facebook login working.

Now, through the code how do I know if a user is logged in through facebook and how do I get his facebook ID, his friends info etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Please check your AuthType variable , it will map to Facebook or costume authentication type.